# Arduino UNO with LCD, strange readings from rotary encoder

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I have an I2C 16x2 LCD display connected to an Arduino Uno's `A4 (SDA)` and `A5 (SCL)` pins. No problem with the display, it works properly.

Then I have a rotary encoder connected to pins `D3 (INT1)` and `D4`. The `INT1` pin is used as interrupt to read the encoder, and the reading is sent via `Serial.print()` to the Serial monitor. There are debounce CAPs connected to the rotary encoder. The encoder pins use the Arduino's internal pullups.

The interrupt is attached to read `encoderPinA` when `encoderPinB` is falling from `HIGH` to `LOW`. When turning the rotary clockwise, `encoderPinA` is `LOW`, and when turning it counter-clockwise, `encoderPinA` is `HIGH`.

Now, when there is nothing in the main `loop`, I get `++++++++++` signs on the serial monitor when turning the rotary clockwise, and `----------` signs when turning it counter-clockwise, as I should.

But if I uncomment those two lines that print to the LCD, I start to get erratic readings from the rotary encoder, like this: `-++-++-++-+++-++-+++-++--+`.

What's going on? Is the LCD interfering with interrupt pins?

```
#define encoderPinA 4
#define encoderPinB 3

#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(encoderPinA, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(encoderPinB, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt (digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderPinB), readEncoder, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  //lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  //lcd.print("test");
}

void readEncoder() {
  if (digitalRead(encoderPinA) == LOW) Serial.print("+");
  else Serial.print("-");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry folks, this problem was clearly a cable related issue.

I was using the same non-shielded flat cable to carry out rotary and lcd signals, and there was some interference, because when I switch to separate cables, the erratic behaviour is gone.